# Does Blender python run slower when strictly typing?

Tags: python, scripting, performance, optimization

I have a code snippet without strict data-typing:

```
def get_color(bm, materials, i):
    m = materials[bm.faces[i].material_index]
    if m[2]:
        # either direct color
        return m[2]
    else:
        # or the color in the image texture
        uv = bm.faces[i].loops[0][bm.loops.layers.uv[0]].uv
        px = int((m[3][0]-1) * uv.x)
        py = int((m[3][1]-1) * uv.y)
        pixel = 4 * (m[3][0] * py + px)
        return Color((round(m[4][pixel]*255), round(m[4][pixel+1]*255), round(m[4][pixel+2]*255)))
```

And then transformed it to use strict data-typing which gives me the advantage to better understand and read the code. But I noticed (I could be wrong) that Blender python runs slightly slower (measured with `time.time()`) than regular python without the Blender UI. The code got longer as well which I thought might affect performance. Based on my research it should not really do any difference in performance. Is this even recommended?

```
def get_color(bm: BMesh, materials: List[Tuple], i: int) -> Color:
    faces: BMFaceSeq = bm.faces
    face: BMFace = faces[i]
    idx: int = face.material_index
    if idx < 0:
        return Color(0, 0, 0, 255)

    m: Tuple = materials[idx] # (1, <bpy_struct, Material("Material.008") at 0x0000025E3679BA08, evaluated>, Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), None, None)
    color: Color = m[2]
    coords: bpy_types.bpy_prop_array = m[3]
    colors: Tuple[float, ...] = m[4]
    if coords:
        elem_seq: BMElemSeq = face.loops
        loop: BMLoop = elem_seq[0]
        loop_seq: BMLoopSeq = bm.loops
        layers: BMLayerAccessLoop = loop_seq.layers
        collection: BMLayerCollection = layers.uv
        item: BMLayerItem = collection[0]
        luv: BMLoopUV = loop[item]
        uv: Vector = luv.uv
        px: int = int((coords[0]-1) * uv.x)
        py: int = int((coords[1]-1) * uv.y)
        pixel = 4 * (coords[0] * py + px)
        return Color((round(colors[pixel]*255), round(colors[pixel+1]*255), round(colors[pixel+2]*255)))
    return color
```

Comment: You can test it it with timeit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-do-i-measure-elapsed-time-in-python. I suspect if there is a difference, it's probably not perceivable in your example. But testing it is a good idea, since you will know how it is with your specific code, hardware and setup. You probably want to repeat the stuff that executes really fast in loop a few thousand times for it to be more accurate and repeat the test itself a few times.

Comment: yeah i did the `time.time()` to measure and that's where i saw a slight difference that's why i wanted to get more input if it is even advisable to code like that. i noticed it makes the code longer as well which i thought may impact performance.

Comment: I am sure people would test it if you shared code that is possible to copy-paste and  run.  Having to write a lot of stuff around the snippet shared to be able to test it is probably an obstacle.

Comment: The gist of the discussion revolves around the usage of strictly-typed Python and its potential impact, rather than delving into specific code examples. The provided code was merely an illustration. If you're knowledgeable in this area, you should likely already have an answer without needing to test any specific script. No offense intended.

Comment: No, you are right - I am not knowledgeable in the area. I am just familiar with Blender's Python API and I only know it's not particularly common to code like this with Blender's Python API. It is a good question.

Comment: It shouldn't, no. Your snippets are different in ways other than typing though. You should compare the same code, just with types stripped out.

Comment: yes you're right i totally forgot i modified the code because i can't do the typing without breaking the lines apart. thank you guys for your inputs! :)